# Connecting to an Apache Derby/JavaDB database using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: jdbc, derby, javadb, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've been trying to connect to an **Apache Derby/JavaDB** embedded database using **Oracle SQL Developer** but without much success.

I've tried to create a new connection using the following JDBC URL:

`jdbc:derby:/path/to/file/database.derby;create=true`

which resulted in an error:

`Status : Failure -Test failed: Invalid connection info specified. Verify the URL format for the specified driver.`

Previously I've added `derby.jar` through **Tools > Preferences > Database > Third Party JDBC Drivers**.

Given that JavaDB is now a supported Oracle product I'm not understanding why is not better integrated with its development tools.

Any guidance will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not about embedded progtamming.  Retagged.

Comment: That error message is not a Derby error message, it must be coming from the IDE.

Comment: I believe it's actually a JDBC error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derby url seems wrong. You need to point the url to the directory of the database, not the database itself.

```
jdbc:derby:/path/to/file/;create=true
```

### Have a look at the [examples](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/devguide/rdevdvlp22102.html#rdevdvlp22102).

> `jdbc:derby:/reference/phrases/french`
>
> Open a connection to the database /reference/phrases/french.
>
> On a UNIX system, this would be the path of the directory. On a
>   Windows system, the path would be C:\reference\phrases\french if the
>   current drive were C. If a jar file storing databases were in the
>   user's classpath, this could also be a path within the jar file.

### From the [docs](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/devguide/cdevdvlp17453.html):

> The connection URL syntax is as follows:
>
> `jdbc:derby:[subsubprotocol:][databaseName][;attribute=value]`
>
> Subsubprotocol, which is not typically specified, determines how Derby
>   looks for a database: in a **directory**, in memory, in a class path, or
>   in a jar file. Subsubprotocol is one of the following:
>
> **directory**: The default. Specify this explicitly only to distinguish a database that might be ambiguous with one on the class
>   path.

Answer (score 0):

try connecting to the **Derby DB** using the **Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers** instead of **Oracle SQL Developer**. In the latest versions it is has the full integrations.